# need capitalize words with special chars in PHP

Tags: php, capitalize

ucwords doesn't capitalize foreign chars like öüäõ

so I need a solution, which will make "öösel" into "Öösel"

Is there a simple way to do it with regexp or I have to check all the characters manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the [mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension installed, you can use the [`mb_convert_case`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) function, specifying `MB_CASE_TITLE` as the `$mode` parameter.

Comment: How long have I been working with PHP without knowing about this..?

Answer (score 5):

<s>You can give a try to strtoupper() which works fine for me with French.</s>
*Sorry I hadn't seen it was ucwords...*

Otherwise, this should work:

> mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other answers, which suffer from the same problems as ucwords, you might take a look at keeping [this variation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php#92317) in your toolbox.